# Cannot implicitly convert type long to a Object Model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to assign a object ie..(`Member`) with a `ID` property with a `ID` from another Object that has the property declared as a `long` and I am getting

> cannot implicitly convert type long to Genesis.Domain.Entities.Member.

I am not understanding the casting or if it can be done, but if anybody can enlighten me, I would greatly appreciate it.

The error is on the last line of code.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult CreateThread(Forum_Posts p, int forumID, MemberData md, HttpPostedFileBase image1, HttpPostedFileBase image2, HttpPostedFileBase image3, HttpPostedFileBase image4)
{

    MemberEditModel editMember = new MemberEditModel();
    editMember.Member = GenesisRepository.GetMember(md.MemberGUID);

    if (editMember.Member != null)
    {
        editMember.ScreenName   = editMember.Member.ScreenName;
        editMember.MemberID = **editMember.Member.MemberID**;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the type of `editMember.MemberID` is it `int`/`long` or `Genesis.Domain.Entities.Member`

Comment: It is of type Genesis.Domain.Entities.Member

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `editMember.MemberID` and `editMember.Member.MemberID` are from different types.

Since `editMember.MemberID` is of type `Genesis.Domain.Entities.Member` (not `long`) you are getting the exception.

In order for your code to work properly just replace

```
editMember.MemberID = editMember.Member.MemberID;
```

with

```
editMember.MemberID = editMember.Member;
```